# How to stop a running bash script after it's current running command finished?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

There is a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 do_something_1.py
python3 do_something_2.py
python3 do_something_3.py
python3 do_something_4.py
python3 do_something_5.py
```

If it's running `python3 do_something_3.py` now.

How can I tell bash process that after `python3 do_something_3.py` exits by itself(don't kill subprocess, wait it), no longer run subsequent commands `python3 do_something_4.py`,`python3 do_something_5.py` anymore?

Comment: `python3 do_something_3.py && exit 0`?

Comment: script already running, change script file may not work.

Comment: there is no possibility then knowing if `python3 do_something_3.py` failed of succeed out of your script (you may only can verify if it had given output as you were expected then go ahead and kill your running script), other than that you needed error handling in your script beforehand.

Comment: I want bash process wait `python3 do_something_3.py` subprocess normally exit (don't send signal to kill the subprocess), once the child process exits, skip the subsequent commands like 4.py & 5.py .

Comment: you are going in a wrong way, work on error handling in your script at first place

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `while` loop to check if `do_something_3.py` is still running (e.g. using `pgrep`) and `sleep` as long it is.

After the loop, kill your script.

```bsh
while pgrep -f do_something_3.py >/dev/null ; then
    sleep 0.1
done && pkill -9 myscript
```

- The exact `pkill` command depends how you named and called the script, you might want to test it with `pgrep myscript` or find out the PID and use `kill -9 PID`.
- Note, that this is nowhere ideal, because you won't find the exact timing to stop your script before `do_something_4.py` has started.

Answer (score 1):

Signals are the simplest solution here. From the Bash `man` page:

> If `bash` is waiting for a command to complete and receives a signal for which a `trap` has been set, the `trap` **will not be executed until the command completes**.

An example (`thescript.sh`):

```bsh
trap 'echo "Exiting on USR1 after command"; exit' USR1

echo 'Beginning'
sleep 2  # long-running command
echo 'Middle'
sleep 2  # long-running command
echo 'End'
```

This will exit after the first `sleep` completes:

```bsh
./thescript.sh &
pid="$!"
sleep 1
kill -USR1 "$pid"  # roughly the middle of first sleep
wait -n "$pid"
```

This will exit after the second `sleep` completes:

```bsh
./thescript.sh &
pid="$!"
sleep 3
kill -USR1 "$pid"  # roughly the middle of second sleep
wait -n "$pid"
```